# Audio encryption with analog conversion

Tags: python, audio, cryptography, analog-digital-converter, digital-analog-converter

I have recently started using python and I have no special knowledge of cryptography.

What I want to do:
I want to transmit digital encoded data (speech/wav) trough an analog signal, record this analog signal and decode it after that. 
A little like this: http://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/voice.htm#digital but with AES instead a XOR-Operation.

My problem:
I record a WAV file and Encrypt it with AES. The decryption of this file works fine.
Now I play this signal through a speaker and record it with a microphone again. Now, when I decrypted the mic-recorded file, I get only a file full of noise.

Do I lose by its 2x analog/digital-conversion too much information to decipher to after that?
Is AES perhaps the wrong encryption for my application?

Comment: why is your title in german? O_o

Comment: Why would you expect a bit-for-bit perfect copy of the file after it is played and recorded with analogue equipment? As that's what you'd need for it to decrypt correctly after being played through speakers. Perhaps you'd be better off explaining what you are trying to achieve in general.

Comment: I want to decrypt a audio file or stream (for example: speech), transmit it analog (for example: trough a phone) and decode it after that.

Comment: This will never be possible, sorry. Minor changes in the binary representation of the signal due to analog transport will lead to huge differences after decryption.

Comment: So, my only choice is a XOR encryption with lack security, right?

Comment: Seconded. Watermarks that can survive digital->analogue->digital conversions are possible but they have to be carefully designed. What you are trying to do is not possible without perfect fidelity.

Comment: No, you don't get to do these sorts of conversions on DIGITAL data and expect to be able to make sense of the output after an analogue stage.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum_software#Tape as that's basically what you are trying to do. If you can convert your audio to that format then you can transmit it via analogue (e.g. tape) channels.

Comment: @PaulC Ok. I have to convert my encrypted data into something, that can be transmited as acoustic signal. Is it possible to do this with software or do I need a hardware solution (DSP)?

Comment: The spectrum managed it ok without a DSP. In fact the (pseudocode) instructions for doing that were in the link I sent. On tape the data is analogue. Inside the speccy it's digital. Exactly what you are after.

Comment: You will need to look at modulation techniques, and then most probably error detection and correction algorithms.  This is likely to require substantial DSP.

Comment: @PaulC it also did it with very low data-rates.   Remember that state-of-the-art audio modulation at audio rates achieves about 56kbps over telephone lines using a considerable amount of adaptive equalisation.

Comment: good point. But if the OP can get it going at spectrum data rates then that's progress I suspect...

Comment: @PaulC Would it be a good idea to use the XMODEM (or ZMODEM) protocol to do that? I've seen, there's a package for python.

Comment: Is there? Wow! I'm afraid I've not used that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no block based encryption/decryption schemes allow for bit errors to "gracefully" pass through the decryption, but I might be wrong. If any such schemes exist, they're propably quiet exotic and will create a bunch of other problems for you. Therefore, you need to do the analog transfer lossless.

This problem has luckily been solved before. The solution is a modem. And it should be one tailored to the transmission channel, meaning you can't use the same modem for both telephone and air transmission channels.

Modems are actually pretty hard to design and implement (even though they're dirt cheap), so unless you have experience in this area I would suggest to get some help :-)

Regards